# Русские буквы javascript

Tags: javascript

подскажите функцию javascript который вернул вместо таких кодов нормальную строку

```
\u041b\u044e\u0431\u0438\u043c\u044b\u0435 \u0444\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043c\u044b
->
Любимые фильмы
```

Comment: в для чего? это utf8, при правильной странице проблем с этим нет никаких...

Answer (score 1):

unescape